# User-variable to select value from previous row fine in MySQL 5.5 but in 5.6 it seems to be running the SELECT part of the query in a different order

Tags: mysql

I have a rather unusual issue which has come up when moving to a staging server from a local environment. The MySQL version is different but I am unable to find any reason why this issue would have occurred.

The code I am using is:

```
DECLARE _first_event_time datetime;

SELECT event_time INTO _first_event_time
FROM session_events
WHERE session_id = _session_id
ORDER BY event_id ASC LIMIT 0,1;

-- Select Data

SELECT event_id,
event_time,
timediff(event_time, _first_event_time) AS event_time_from_start,
(@previous := unix_timestamp(event_time) - @previous) AS event_duration,
(@previous := unix_timestamp(event_time)) AS previous_event_timestamp
FROM session_events e,

(SELECT @previous:=0) c
ORDER BY event_id ASC LIMIT 0, 400;
```

What I would expect is in the following results, which is what I am getting from 5.5 running on my DEV version running MAMP:

```
+----------+------------------+-----------------------+----------------+--------------------------+
| event_id |    event_time    | event_time_from_start | event_duration | previous_event_timestamp |
+----------+------------------+-----------------------+----------------+--------------------------+
|     5074 | 24/09/2015 20:35 | 00:00:00              |     1443123315 |               1443123315 |
|     5075 | 24/09/2015 20:35 | 00:00:02              |              2 |               1443123317 |
|     5076 | 24/09/2015 20:35 | 00:00:03              |              1 |               1443123318 |
|     5077 | 24/09/2015 20:35 | 00:00:03              |              0 |               1443123318 |
|     5078 | 24/09/2015 20:35 | 00:00:04              |              1 |               1443123319 |
|     5079 | 24/09/2015 20:35 | 00:00:05              |              1 |               1443123320 |
|     5080 | 24/09/2015 20:35 | 00:00:06              |              1 |               1443123321 |
|     5081 | 24/09/2015 20:35 | 00:00:06              |              0 |               1443123321 |
|     5082 | 24/09/2015 20:35 | 00:00:07              |              1 |               1443123322 |
|     5083 | 24/09/2015 20:35 | 00:00:08              |              1 |               1443123323 |
|     5084 | 24/09/2015 20:35 | 00:00:09              |              1 |               1443123324 |
|     5085 | 24/09/2015 20:35 | 00:00:10              |              1 |               1443123325 |
+----------+------------------+-----------------------+----------------+--------------------------+
```

But instead the data is coming out like this (please note that the data values are different as I have created the same values on both servers but you can see where the data is being offset, the code in the stored procedure is identical on both servers):

```
+----------+------------------+-----------------------+----------------+--------------------------+
| event_id |    event_time    | event_time_from_start | event_duration | previous_event_timestamp |
+----------+------------------+-----------------------+----------------+--------------------------+
|     5307 | 24/09/2015 20:32 | 00:00:00              |            -17 |               1443123174 |
|     5308 | 24/09/2015 20:33 | 00:00:07              |     1443123181 |               1443123181 |
|     5309 | 24/09/2015 20:33 | 00:00:08              |             -7 |               1443123182 |
|     5310 | 24/09/2015 20:33 | 00:00:09              |              2 |               1443123183 |
|     5311 | 24/09/2015 20:33 | 00:00:11              |              3 |               1443123185 |
|     5312 | 24/09/2015 20:33 | 00:00:12              |              3 |               1443123186 |
|     5313 | 24/09/2015 20:33 | 00:00:13              |              2 |               1443123187 |
|     5314 | 24/09/2015 20:33 | 00:00:14              |              2 |               1443123188 |
|     5315 | 24/09/2015 20:33 | 00:00:15              |              2 |               1443123189 |
|     5316 | 24/09/2015 20:33 | 00:00:15              |              1 |               1443123189 |
|     5317 | 24/09/2015 20:33 | 00:00:17              |              2 |               1443123191 |
|     5318 | 24/09/2015 20:33 | 00:00:18              |             18 |               1443123192 |
+----------+------------------+-----------------------+----------------+--------------------------+
```

The timezone shouldn't make a difference as this is being run from data and a stored procedure. I have also tried changing from a timestamp to just using a datediff using the follow:

```
, ( TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(event_time, @previous))) AS event_duration
, ( @previous := event_time ) AS previous_event_timestamp
```

Looking into this a bit further it seems to be that issue is somewhere with the ORDER BY clause, it seems to be selecting the results in an unsorted order when populating the @previous field on the initial run through on this server as if I remove the ORDER BY clause and just set @previous to event_time then the order is the one that is used that is causing the issue.

If I run just a select statement without the @previous and no ORDER BY clause the dataset returned by the 5.6 server seems to match the unusual order being shown in the 2nd example where the @previous seems to be picking random values.

I can only thing that the part of the SELECT statement that is running through the data and setting the @previous value is running first then when it returns to data it then runs the ORDER BY which is where the issue is coming from.

Looking through the MySQL manual I have not found anything (at least not what I have been able to attribute to why this is happening) between 5.5 and 5.6. I presume there is a way to get this working.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I can not figure out why it is electing in the order it is prior to the ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL *explicitly* warns against using variables and assigning them in different expressions in the same `select`.  I would suggest you do this using a subquery:

```
SELECT t.*,
       (unix_timestamp(event_time) - previous_event_timestamp) as event_duration
FROM (SELECT event_id, event_time,
             timediff(event_time, _first_event_time) AS event_time_from_start,
             if((@pp := @p) = null, null, -- never happens
                if(@p := unix_timestamp(event_time), @pp, @pp)
               ) AS previous_event_timestamp
      FROM session_events e CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @p := 0, @pp := 0) c
      ORDER BY event_id ASC
      LIMIT 0, 400
     ) t;
```

The `if` logic is just a way of putting the assignments in the same statement.  The first assigns `@pp` to be the current previous value (in `@p`).  The second reassign `@p`, and then returns `@pp`.

The outer query then does the calculations on the value.

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) says:

> As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never
>   assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same
>   statement.

It is best to avoid "features" that the documentation explicitly warns against using.

Comment: That makes sense, I will try that out.The original code was an adaptation of a snippet I found when looking for how to update a column with information from a previous row so was unaware of the issues that it might cause being warned against.

Comment: It is sad that misleading answers get upvotes and acceptance, even when they are not correct.  This seems to happen particularly with MySQL in this case and with the use of MySQL's `group by` extensions.  I try to add a comment when I come across such answers.

Comment: Finally managed to get around to looking at this properly. It looks like there is something missing. `if((@pp := @p) is null,
                if(@p := unix_timestamp(event_time), @pp, @pp)
               ) AS previous_event_timestamp` Seems to be missing an else statement.

Comment: @Lee . . . It was actually missing the "then" part.  I put in `= NULL`, because that never evaluates to true.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it has worked perfectly and is returning exactly as expected on both systems.